# How do one know which folder is created by which Android apps?

Tags: applications, uninstallation, file-management

From my understanding, a majority of Android apps may have created some folders on either local storage or the SD Card.

So, how do I know which folders belong to which apps? (I know that some apps have settings that show you which folder that they have created but are there any solutions where one can easily find all the folder corresponding to their apps in a list similar like the one shown below?)

```
====================================
| Apps Name |   Folder             |
====================================
| ABB       | \sdcard\actionbb     |
| ZZX       | \sdcard\zoneX        |
|           | \local\zoneXconf     |
====================================
```

This is because, sometimes, when one un-installs an app, the un-installation does not remove these folders.

Answer (score 4):

If you open a file as Context.MODE_PRIVATE, then the file is created in /data/data/app_packagename and is only accessible to your app. You can see the permission and owner of these files in command line.

```
adb shell ls -al

drwxr-x--x    1 app_28   app_28        2048 Dec  6  2011 com.android.mms
```

But files in sdcard is public to all user, so you cannot find out which folder belong to which app.

> Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be
>   modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer
>   files on a computer.

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) for details.

Comment: Though, some apps store their contents on SD card in a directory similar to that on internal storage, something like `/mnt/sdcard/data/com.myapp`, in which case you can check this package name (here: `com.myapp`) with the playstore's web frontend, adding it after the "`id=`" parameter. Unfortunately, these kind of exceptions are few...

Comment: So, there is no other way to check which folder inside the sdcard that belong to which apps unless one check the settings inside the apps and also the apps have information that tell user where they store their files into which folder in the SDcard. However, I still hope that there are such application that can provide the list. (or maybe google play can tell us what folders are created when install the apps, just like what it did to the permission - it tell the user what permission the apps are asking for)

Comment: What about human heuristic based on file/folder creation/modification time? I'm just reasoning, I didn't tried it yet. But if I installed an app yesterday, and it created a folder on SD Card, then the folder should have a creation time that reflects that. Looking for files in already existent folders would be a pain, but should be still possible.